# How to logout sessions in oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I'm trying to avoid users to login in different computers.

I want to create a Login view, if the user is already logged and you try to login with that user, the app will display a message "user already logged" and have the option of closing the open session with a link or button.

**EDIT :** Apex Version 5.1.1.00.08, no possibility to updating this version.

I've tried multiple ways to close the session but none have worked so far.

**FIRST ACTION :**

Create the url to log out.

I'm taking the **APEX_SESSION_ID** from the table **apex_workspace_sessions**

[image]

http://xxxxxxxx.com/apex/apex_authentication.logout?p_app_id=100&p_session_id=APEX_SESSION_ID

But when I open the link it doesn't log out the user with that **APEX_SESSION_ID**

**SECOND ACTION :**

I tried to create a function to log out the session extracting **APEX_SESSION_ID** from the table **apex_workspace_sessions** but it's not working either by generating this error :

**ORA-06550: line 2, column 11: PLS-00328: A subprogram body must be defined for the forward declaration of DELETE_SESSION. ORA-06550: line 6, column 16: PLS-00302: component 'DELETE_SESSION' must be declared ORA-06550: line 6, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
declare 

procedure delete_session (p_session_id in number default wwv_flow.g_instance );

begin
    apex_session.delete_session (
    p_session_id => APEX_SESSION_ID );
end;
```

the **p_session_id** in the image is **APEX_SESSION_ID** that already exists in the table **apex_workspace_sessions**

**THIRD ACTION :**

I tried to run the query

```
DELETE FROM APEX_050000.wwv_flow_sessions$ WHERE ID = APEX_SESSION_ID;
```

displaying the error : **ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

and the query

```
DELETE FROM apex_workspace_sessions WHERE APEX_SESSION_ID = APEX_SESSION_ID;
```

displaying the error : **ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**

**FOURTH ACTION :**

I tried to use the LOGOUT PROCEDURE from the official oracle docs but didn't work either

```
apex_authentication.logout(APEX_SESSION_ID, :APP_ID);
```

no error or anything to display.

Does anyone knows how to log out a user from another computer ?

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes understanding why someone is trying to do something can help with picking the correct implementation. Why are you trying to do this? Why does it matter if they log in on different computers or browsers?

Comment: I dont want to have multiple sessions for one single user logged in different computers, just one session for one user, kind of like web whastapp, security issues, thanks @DanMcGhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a custom table.

**Create the table**

```
create table most_recent_logins (
  id         number generated by default on null as identity  
             constraint most_recent_logins_id_pk primary key,
  username   varchar2(255) not null,
  app_id     number not null,
  session_id number not null
             constraint most_recent_log_session_id_unq unique,
  login_date date not null,
  constraint most_recent_log_user_app_unq unique (username, app_id)
);
```

**Create post-auth process**

Go to Shared Components > Authentication Schemes and select the current scheme. Put the following in the PL/SQL code field:

```
procedure post_auth
is

  cursor mrl_cur
  is
    select *
    from most_recent_logins
    where app_id = :app_id
      and username = :app_user
    for update;

  mrl_rec mrl_cur%rowtype;

begin

  open mrl_cur;
  fetch mrl_cur into mrl_rec;

  if mrl_cur%notfound
  then
    insert into most_recent_logins (
      username,
      app_id,
      session_id,
      login_date
    ) values (
      :app_user,
      :app_id,
      :app_session,
      sysdate
    );
  else
    update most_recent_logins
    set session_id = :app_session,
      login_date = sysdate
    where current of mrl_cur;
  end if;

  close mrl_cur;

end;
```

**Create an application process**

Go to Shared Components > Application Process and click **Create >**. Set Name to **Check most recent login**, then click **Next >**. Enter the following code in PL/SQL code and click **Next >**:

```
declare

  l_mr_session_id number;

begin

  select session_id
  into l_mr_session_id
  from most_recent_logins
  where username = :app_user
    and app_id = :app_id;

  if l_mr_session_id != :app_session
  then
    apex_util.redirect_url('f?p=' || :app_id || ':9999');
  end if;

end;
```

Configure the condition so that the process doesn't run on the login page, then click **Create Process**.

That should do it.

Comment: Actually the second option, creating a table in order to control the login is what i want, but i dont need to create a new table, that's why I want to select and update the apex_workspace_sessions, therefore if any session is deleted from apex_workspace_sessions table, that would be a sort of log out from the application.

Unfortunatelly, I can't operate that table like displaying in **third action**, you know how to deleting records (sessions) from that table on application-level ? Thanks @DanMcGhan

Comment: The APEX owned tables are out of your control. You can only use exposed APIs. Since you’re not on 18+, you don’t have access to the API you need. Creating a custom table is a simple work around to implement the functionality you need. Why not do it?

Comment: Well creating a new table is not an issue, the thing is, I should be able to log out the session if the user is requesting login into another computer.

I was running the Post-Authentication Procedure code you made but it didn't work either 

[Error Post-Authentication Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqbCa.png)

Same error as the **second action**, do you know what could it be ? I have the Apex Version 5.1.1.00.08, I can't update this version, company reasons. @DanMcGhan

Comment: You are not on APEX 18+. You do not have the API available. Either upgrade APEX or create a table.

Comment: You are right, I will create the table but I'm not quite sure how that works, how could I manage closing the sessions through that table if there is another table that is already doing that function ?. Thanks @DanMcGhan

Comment: Don't worry about that... I updated the answer to use a custom table. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

What version of apex are you on ? If you are on 18.1 or higher you can use  `apex_session.delete_session` to do all the work for you.

Comment: Sorry, its the 5.1.1.00.08, I edited the answer, actually i tried that option in the **second action** but didn't work, @Koen